# Restricting the image upload based on 2*2 Inches

Tags: visualforce

Currently I had a page where we upload the image to Amazon AWS s3 bucket directly without saving in salesforce. I would like to restrict the Image upload based on Image Inches i.e. the user should be able to upload only 2*2 inches passport image or other need to throw an error message.

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:component controller="AWS_Upload">
  <style> 
    body { background-color: #e4e4e2;}
    #uploadForm {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#f2f2f2));
    }

    #mainContent {
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }

    h4.fileToUpload {
    margin-top: 0.0em;
    font-size: 18pt;
    }

  #btn_submit {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }


    input[type=submit]{
    opacity: 1.0;
    background-color: #98002e;
    Color: #ffffff;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.10) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.10));
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    #file {
    opacity: 1.0;
    background-color: #e4e4e2;
    Color: #98002e;

  cursor: pointer;
  }

  #float {
  display: block;
  background-color: #cec6c0;
  width: 580px;    
  color: #002147;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  }


    #submit { display: none;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id ="mainContent">
    <form action="https://s3.amazonaws.com/{!awsKeySet.Name}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
        <input type="hidden"  name="key"  id="key" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{!awsKeySet.AWS_AccessKey_Id__c}" /> 
        <input type="hidden"  name="policy" value="{!policy}" /> 
        <input type="hidden"  name="signature" value="{!signedPolicy}" /> 
        <input type="hidden"  name="acl" value="{!acessType}" /> 
        <input type="hidden"  name="Content-Type" value="{!Content_Type}" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="{!ForRedirect}" />

        <h4 class="fileToUpload" style="color: #004990;" >Select a photo for: </h4>
        <h4 class="fileToUpload"> <span style="color: #98002e;">{!ContactFName} {!ContactLName}</span> </h4><br />
        <div class="row">
        <input type="file" size="50" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" onchange="previewFile();" style="margin: 10px 0"/> 
        </div>

        <div id="fileName"></div>
        <div id="fileSize"></div>
        <div id="fileType"><img src="" id="preview" alt="Image preview..." style="max-width:540px; max-height: 200px;" /> <br />
        File Size is : <b><label id="lblSize" /></b>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="submit" >
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"  id="btn_submit" />
        </div>
        <div id="progressNumber"></div>
    </form> 
</div>

<div id="float">
    <h4 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">Directions</h4>
    <ol>
        <li>Click "Choose File".</li>
        <li>Select an image.<br /><b>Supported File Types:</b> <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #98002e">jpeg, jpg, png, bmp, &amp; gif</span> less than 1MB.</li>
        <li>Click Upload.</li>
    </ol>
    <h4 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">Guildlines</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>Image ratio should be <b>3 x 2</b> and the width be less than 600 pixels wide. </li>
        <li>The smaller the file the faster it will load. Even though we allow files sides up to 1MB (1024KB) images should be around <b>100KB</b> or less.</li>
    </ul>
</div>

                                        <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function () { 

                                            var _requestBucket;

                                            $("#btn_submit").click(function(event){
                                                //alert(1);
                                                event.preventDefault();

                                                var ID = '{!ContactID}'; // contact ID
                                                var ID4 = ID.substring(11,15); //ger last four of contact ID
                                                var first = '{!ContactFName}'; // contact first name
                                                var last = '{!ContactLName}'; // contact last name
                                                var last1 = last.charAt(0);
                                                var file_ext = $("#file").val().replace(/.+[\\\/]/, ""); // selected file name and  file extension
                                                var ext = file_ext.substring(file_ext.lastIndexOf(".")+1) // select file extension
                                                var time = '{!presentDate2}';
                                                time = time.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "_");

                                                var folder = 'CP/'; // Folder in AWS Bucket

                                                //   _file = $("#file").val().replace(/.+[\\\/]/, "");

                                                var _file = folder.concat(last1,"/",last, "_", first, "-", ID4,"_", time, ".", ext); // build file name for AWS. ex "Le_Vu-o2Fi.png"

                                                console.log('_file'+_file);
                                                $("#key").val(_file);
                                                $("#uploadForm").submit(); 


                                            });



                                        });

                                          function previewFile(){
                                              var preview = document.getElementById('preview'); //selects the query named img
                                              var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
                                              var reader  = new FileReader();

                                              reader.onloadend = function () {
                                                  preview.src = reader.result;

                                              }

                                              if (file) {
                                                  reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL

                                              } else {
                                                  preview.src = "";
                                              }
                                          }

                                          previewFile();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#file").change(function () { 
        var fname = $("#file").val().replace(/.+[\\\/]/, ""); 
        var re = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.gif|\.png)$/i;            

        if(!re.exec(fname))  {
            alert("File extension not supported!");

            } else {
                          if (this.files[0].size > 1048576) { 

                              alert("Please select a photo less than 1 MB.");
                              document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'none';
                              var iSize = ($("#file")[0].files[0].size / 1024); 
                              if (iSize / 1024 > 2) 
                              { 
                                  if (((iSize / 1024) / 1024) > 1) 
                                  { 
                                      iSize = (Math.round(((iSize / 1024) / 1024) * 100) / 100);
                                      $("#lblSize").html( iSize + "Gb <br /> <span style='color:#ef4123; font-size: 18px;'>Please selct a file less than 2MB.</span>");

                                  }
                                  else
                                  { 
                                      iSize = (Math.round((iSize / 1024) * 100) / 100)
                                      $("#lblSize").html( iSize + "Mb <br /> <span style='color:#ef4123; font-size: 18px;'>Please selct a file less than 2MB.</span>");

                                  } 
                              } 
                              else 
                              {
                                  iSize = (Math.round(iSize * 100) / 100)
                                  $("#lblSize").html( iSize  + "kb");

                              }   

                          }    else {
                              document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'inline'; 
                              var iSize = ($("#file")[0].files[0].size / 1024); 
                              if (iSize / 1024 > 2) 
                              { 
                                  if (((iSize / 1024) / 1024) > 1) 
                                  { 
                                      iSize = (Math.round(((iSize / 1024) / 1024) * 100) / 100);
                                      $("#lblSize").html( iSize + "Gb"); 
                                  }
                                  else
                                  { 
                                      iSize = (Math.round((iSize / 1024) * 100) / 100)
                                      $("#lblSize").html( iSize + "Mb"); 
                                  } 
                              } 
                              else 
                              {
                                  iSize = (Math.round(iSize * 100) / 100)
                                  $("#lblSize").html( iSize  + "kb"); 
                              }   
                          }
                }
                      }); 
});



  </script>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: isn't this really a question for stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

You are using javascript to make the call so it is better to handle this inside javascript itself. following code will handle this

```
function displayPreview(files) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var img = new Image();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        img.src = e.target.result;
        fileSize = Math.round(files.size / 1024);
        alert("File size is " + fileSize + " kb");

        img.onload = function () {
            alert("width=" + this.width + " height=" + this.height);
            if(this.width==192 && this.height==192)
               alert('File correct');
            else
                 alert("Please upload correct size file");
        };




    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files);

}


$("#file").change(function () {
    var file = this.files[0];
    displayPreview(file);

});
```

Comment: But, you really didn't need jQuery just to attach an event to a file input.

Comment: @sfdcfox that is correct. in that code I am only showing the way he can call the above function.

Comment: this is a off topic question. probably we can close this.

Comment: I'm looking for Image cropping

Comment: for image cropping you can use any image cropping jquery library.